# How to define a blur event listener of a window in titanium (IOS)?

Tags: javascript, ios

I had created a small window when click a button on the base-window,and I had defined a blur event listener of the small window by functioned it when I clicked somewhere which dose not belongs to the small window will close it!However,it doesn't work!I don't know clear of the blur event listener with a window (I just know that close a window will triggered its blur event)!Here is my code:

```js
var base_window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  width:'100%',
  height:'100%'
});

var create_window_btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
  top:'50%',
  left:'20%',
  width:'20%',
  height:'10%',   

  title:'New Window',
  backgroundColor:'red'
});

base_window.add(create_window_btn);
base_window.open();

var new_window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  top:'10%',
  left:'20%',
  width:'50%',
  height:'50%',

  backgroundColor:'red'
});

create_window_btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  new_window.open();
});

new_window.addEventListener('blur',function(e){
  new_window.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre so much! This problem worked out finally. Just as Pierre said, we should use the e.source to define whether the mouse had clicked on the UI-components or not. If clicked on, we define the component click-event function stops its event from propagating any further by coding like this: e.cancelBubble = true. If not, the component parent-component will do it selves click-event good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blur event won't fire for windows on iOS (see [doc](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-blur)).
Also, there's no reason it would fire with your code: Titaniun doesn't provide such a built-in way to handle windows focus / blur.

What about setting a `click` event listener on your base window ?
When `new_window` is open, the event will only fire if you click out of its rect.
If you need filter events according to wether or not `new_window` is open, you can test the `source` property of the `click` event.

```
base_window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    Ti.API.error(e.source)
});
/* Result
source = "[object TiUIWindow]";
*/
```

Comment: Well, I had try your way,but not good! Cause there's a problem with the click event listener of the "base_window"! You know that the "new_window" is open through the "create_window_btn" click event listener which located at the somewhere of the "base_window". I mean the "somewhere" is also located at the scope where out of the "new_window", so the problem comes, when click the "create_window_btn" it not only actioned the "new_window" open event, but also actioned its close event. So, what I see is a blink of the "new_window".

Comment: Indeed! That's because the click event is `bubbling` [(doc here)](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Event_Handling-section-29004896_EventHandling-BubblingandNon-BubblingEvents):

*The Titanium.Event object has two new properties: [...]  **cancelBubble**: If true, stops the event from propagating any further.*

    You can try something like this:   `if(e.source == create_window_btn) { e.cancelBubble = true; }`